zip file and download in angular web that view in webview
Because the server is saving the files separately and not storing their compressed files separately, I need to zip the files again after getting the file content. I'm using jszip library to zip file in angular app, then let user download it, my code look like that:
downloadFile(arrFile) {
 const zip = new JSZip();

 for (let j = 0; j < arrFile.length; j++) {
   zip.file(arrFile[j].file_name, arrFile[j].file_content, { base64: true });
 }

 zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
   // saveAs(content, nameFileZip);

   const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(content);
   window.open(fileUrl);
 });}

It works in Browsers, but not in webview. how can I fix it to work in webview?
